# Função recursiva para input de numero inteiro

Tags: python-2.7, recursão, inteiros

Eu tenho este código mas não funciona muito bem, ou seja, se for inteiro à primeira `numOfValues` fica correto, mas se não for fica com o type `None`, pois o que fica em memória é o primeiro input (que não é inteiro). Gostaria que, independentemente das tentativas que fizer, o `numOfValues` ficasse sempre com o valor do ultimo input, e a função parava quando inserisse um inteiro, logo ficaria `numOfValues = INT` (quando a função retorna `x`)

```
def return_int():
  x = raw_input("Number of names to insert?\n")
  try: 
    int(x)
    return int(x)
  except ValueError:
    print "must be an integer"
    return_int()

numOfValues = return_int()
print numOfValues
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que só deva faltar um `return` quando capturada a exceção.

```
return return_int()
```

Ficando assim o código:

```
def return_int():
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Number of names to insert?\n"))   
        return x
    except ValueError:
        print "must be an integer"
        return return_int()

numOfValues = return_int()
print numOfValues
```

Saída:

```
$ python foo.py
Number of names to insert?
1
1
$ python foo.py
Number of names to insert?
ZZZZZZ
must be an integer
Number of names to insert?
2
2
$
```

Comment: Acredita muito bem. Obrigado era isso mesmo